# Can I use the result of an sqldatasource (a simple string) to use it as a parameter of another sqldatasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle, sqldatasource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="UsersUsernameSQL" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries %>" 
     ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries.ProviderName %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT &quot;FIRSTNAME&quot; FROM &quot;USERS&quot; WHERE (&quot;USERNAME&quot; = ?)">
     <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UsersNameLabel" Name="USERNAME" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is my code. My query is that I want to select a name where the username equals with the result of the other `SqlDataSource` (this one works fine, I checked it)

So can I set the result of the datasource as a parameter? And if yes, then how?

Comment: Why would you want to do that instead of building it into a single query?

Comment: Well I figured that maybe I dont need the result of the datasource, because I have that already in a text of a label. But then can I use that somehow as a parameter in the query?